issue while converting custom tabs/tab into bootstrap nav tabs/tab
my custom tabs/tab logic
 <!-- <lntds-tabs [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)"> -->
                    <!-- <lntds-tab class="custom-tab-group lntdstabscontainer ml-4 text-center-sm" tabTitle="Archival"> -->

my written nav tabs/tab logic

<ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-left custom-tab ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#archivalTab">Archival</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#retrievalTab">Retrieval</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="archivalTab" class="tab-pane active">

my nav tabs/tab logic is unable to handle the tab change event, and also the selectedtab index. please help me to solve this as i cannot make changes in my .ts file
i did change the lntds-tabs and lntds-tab into the nav tabs and nav tab but i am unable to add the logic which is written in lntd tab to the nav tab

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

if you are using this in angular then use angular routing functionality instead of href
you can create routing to navigate between tabs
<ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-left custom-tab ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="archivalTab">Archival</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="retrievalTab">Retrieval</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="archivalTab" class="tab-pane active">

Routing module:
const routes: Routes = [
  
  {
    path: 'retrievalTab',
    component: retrievalTabComponent
},
 {
    path: 'archivalTab',
    component: archivalTabComponent
}]

Html:
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>

